# Detecting single circle within multiple circles area

Tags: mathematics, geometry, computational-geometry

There are multiple circles with same radius, given another circle in different radius, how to detect the another circle is fully in multiple circles area.

Image below shows left samples is in the area, right is not. 
[image]

Comment: Is the red circle always smaller? Or can it be as big even bigger than the gray circles?

Comment: red circle is always smaller

Answer (score 1):

The first case is as simple as checking whether the offset between the centres added to the radius of the contained circle, is less than the radius of the container circle.

Your second example on the left is a good case to work from. Here we have tried the approach of the first case and it has failed, so we fall back to another approach. Call the left container circle in grey A, the right one B, and the red contained circle C. Examining C against A, you would need to exclude that arc of C which falls outside of A, call the arc D and the remaining arc (A-D). Examining D against B now tells you whether that arc is wholly contained in B; if both arcs (A-D) and D are contained by the set of containers, then D is contained. This analytical approach is probably cleanest and most performant, but there are many corner cases to be aware of.

You can easily extend this to accommodate the third case on the left.

You could also try turning the entire set into arrays of different coloured pixels, and then do examinations pixelwise. This will avoid any corner cases, but is not as elegant and a computationally more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Another trick you can try is exploiting the [Minkowski Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition).

First, combine all your background circles into a compound shape where they overlap, so you have a single sequence of arcs representing the perimeter of each connected blob.

Then, inset this perimeter by the radius of your test circle. (If your background circles have radius `R` and your test circle has radius `r`, then this changes convex arcs in this perimeter to arcs of radius `R - r`, and changes corners where two circles intersect into concave arcs of radius `r`)

This same operation reduces your test circle to a single point. So now you can simply check whether this point is inside the perimeter of any of the islands left by the shrinking.

[image: Example showing circle patterns shrunk by the test circle radius]

While computing these inset compound shapes is not trivial, this technique can be advantageous if you can re-use these shapes after computing them once. For example, if you needed to test dozens or hundreds of candidate positions for the small circle, you can front-load all the hard work into this Minkowski difference, then you only need to do the simpler point-inside-perimeter test for each candidate.

Comment: You don't need to calculate the perimeter of the compound shapes; use the metaball approach. The perimeter is where the energy of the balls equals a certain value.

Comment: While metaballs have a similar blobby look, the math isn't actually the same. For example, if you stack multiple metaballs on the same point, their energy sums together and the radius of the level set increases. But for the problem of determining whether a test circle is contained inside a set of background circles, stacking multiple background circles on the same point doesn't increase the viable containment radius compared to having just one circle there. So metaball methods give a different answer than the one we're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, to traverse the intersection point of all black circles and red circle, and if these points are in the red circle, and then check whether these points are in the black circle, if all so, the red circle must be in the black circle.
[image]

Comment: Ahhh, you needed only the outer ring to be within the grey area, not the whole interior of the disc! An example like this one would be a good addition to the question itself too, to make it unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst these are good ideas, there's the Corner Case of

> What if the Red Circle is completely within a Single Circle?

You would need a check for this as well, which from the sounds of things should likely resemble the "Minkowski Difference" mentioned in DMGregory's Post, but you are simply checking for a Smaller Radius. Basically the Flow Order is thus:

```
if (GreyRad[1]Shell contains RedRad)
{
  if (GreyRad[1]Core contains RedRad)
    Return True
  Else if (GreyRad[1]Inner contains RedRad)
  {
    if (GreyRad[2]Inner contains RedRad)
    {
      if (GreyRad[3]Inner contains RedRad)
        Return True
      Else
        Return False
    }
    Else
      Return False
  }
  Else
    Return False
}
Else
  Return False
```

Which should return True if everything is matched up, False otherwise, now clearly this isn't factoring in for a 2 Radian Pairing, this would only work on a 3 Radian Pairing, as a 2 Radian Pairing would have a smaller Diameter, which would mean you'd want it before the Core but after the 3 in the logical order, but if someone is trying to break the game, chances are you'll want the Core Radian to be called right after the Shell, then you simply work your way in from the Shell, that lowers the Overload chances as the first thing it checks once it recognizes collision is "are they fully within me? If not, how much are they within me?"

Also, don't forget to clamp your variables to prevent Memory Leaks, you don't want to have 5,000,000 variables for GreyRad[]Inner if you only have 30,000 to check against, also useful for breaking accidental infinite loops as you can include an Error Tracker Counter (eg. if Errors > 120 in last 60 sec, kill all threads)

Comment: I am aware that it's covered in the Image they provided, just not the wording.